# Financial Institution For Managing "Allowances"

Tags: withdrawal

I'm interested in finding a financial institution that would provide money management for someone who is severely irresponsible with finances.  Ideally, this service would provide a small allowance to the person and pay bills directly on their behalf.

Does this exist and if so, how would it be need to be setup?

Comment: Would the account contain their own money that they earned, or a gift held in trust for them?

Answer (score 3):

Most modern bank accounts can be set up to automatically pay bills for anyone, even someone who has no control over the account. This account would be in a trustee's name for the untrustworthy party.

An automatic transfer could be set up from the source account to the irresponsible party's bank account to pay their allowance. It would be wise to remove all overdraft capability from the recipients account, but the whole system might help them learn some responsibility.

There are more formal legal structures for forming a long term care-taking trust (with spendthrift provisions to protect the trust from legal action). The trust would need to be maintained by a trustee, resulting in maintenance fees on the principle. It might also help to know if there are legally recognized factors that impair the beneficiaries ability to take care of themselves (substance abuse, depression, age, mental impairment, etc.), but depending on state law, trusts can be designed very flexibly to cover the lifetime of an heir and even their heirs.

Comment: `It would be wise to remove all overdraft capability from the recipients account`.  Do note, however, that this won't guarantee an overdraft will be impossible (may depend on your location and institution).  For instance, when I declined overdraft protection on the last checking account I opened, I was informed that my account could still go negative from charges marked as "recurring", from charges where the actual transaction was carried out without an online authorization, or from a transaction which initially reserved a smaller amount than the actual purchase....

Answer (score 2):

How about the new Mastercard "In Control" card

http://www.pivotalpayments.com/ca/industry-news/mastercard-introduces-in-control-program-to-help-consumers-budget-800077802/

You can set budgets at your bank and go between getting alerts when you go over, or completely declined if you are out of money.  There are going to be obvious loop holes and slack in the system, but this system seems like a pretty neat start.

Combine this with a bank account that does bill pay and you might have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a DIY area. You should talk to a lawyer about setting up a trust.

Also, does the irresponsible person acknowledge that they are irresponsible? Are the legally competent? Or are you looking at a 20 year old with a big check coming down?